# memory address of dynamic array

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, memory-address

```
double *tt;
tt = new double[2];
std::cout << tt[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << tt << std::endl;
```

The result is like this

-1.72723e-77

0x12e6062e0

What is the difference between these two?
I don't know why the two values ​​have different formats (tt[0] is X.~~ but tt there is no point)

Comment: The contents of the memory create by `new` and `new[]` is not initialized. The elements in the array will have *indeterminate* values. And using such values (even printing them like you do with `std::cout << tt[0]`) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And it seems to me that you need to go back to your text-books and study some of the basic. If you don't have any text-books then please invest in [some good ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tt[0]` is dereferencing the pointer to the array `tt` and the result is an expression of type `double`. It is equivalent to `*tt`. There is a random value in that location so you see a random floating-point value being printed.

But `tt` is just a pointer (of type `double*`) and thus when you print it, the address of a memory location (the address of the first byte of the array) is displayed. C-style arrays automatically decay into a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between these two?

One is the value of the object in the array, and the other is the memory address of the object in the array.

> I don't know why the two values ​​have different formats

The formats are different because the two values have different types. One is a `double` and the other is a pointer (`double*`).

P.S. Since you don't initialise the elements of the array, reading the value results in undefined behaviour. This is a bug. Don't ever do that.